# how to add token to header in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, api

I have a web app that I want to use `api` with. I want to fetch a data that needs a token. I already have the token Ii got the token by running the login function in my postman). The question is: where do I put this token? Some say I need to put it in the `headers` but I can't find where to make this `headers`. Here is my code:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('API_GOES_HERE', {
    headers: { Authentication: `Bearer ajsbdjabsjhdbfquhjwbeasbdasdjwbqjbds
  }})
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(json => {
     this.setState({
       contact: json,
       isLoaded: true,
     })
 })
 .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Without the token, the api always returns this `{"message":"missing or malformed jwt"}`. I already tried this data fetch from postman itself and it works, because I already set the token variable with my token.

I censored the endpoint and the token by changing it to `ENDPOINT_API` and `API_TOKEN`. Thanks, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you need to include token in the request header

```
fetch('API_ENDPOINT', {
   headers: { Authentication: `Bearer ${token}`
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => {
    this.setState({
      contact: json,
      isLoaded: true,
    })
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: your code only gave me an empty bracket `[ ]`, do i need to change `token` in this line with my `token` ? `headers: { Authentication: `Bearer ${token}``

Comment: check my updated answer, is it like that ?, it still gave me an empty bracket

Comment: you are missing a backtick at the end of the token.

Comment: still gave me an empty bracket

Comment: what are you logging on the console? You are not getting the missing token message so api is accepting the token

Answer (score -1):

ok i found the solution to this question, i need to put the `content-type` to the headers it self, and add a `https` to the `API_ENDPOINT`, here is the code that works

```
fetch(API_ENDPOINT, {
    headers: { 
      Authorization: `TOKEN`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
  }})
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(json => {
   console.log(json)
     this.setState({
       contact: json,
       isLoaded: true,
     })
 })
 .catch(err => console.log(err));
```